# How would you prove that A \ (A \ B) = A ∩ B is true for all sets A and B?

Tags: formal-proofs

I know how to prove this using a picture of a venn diagram but I am getting stuck solving it using letters. 
This is what I've tried:

Let x $\in$ A $\setminus$(A$\setminus$B)

x $\in$ A such that x $\notin$ B

x $\in$ A such that x $\notin$ A

Therefore x $\in$ A $\cap$ B

I feel like there are some steps before the last one that I'm missing

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Your deduction seems a bit off. The formal way of doing it would be
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
 A \setminus (A\setminus B) &=& \{x \in A \mid x \notin A \setminus B\}\\
&=& \{ x \in A \mid x \in B\} \\
&=& A \cap B
\end{array}$$
Note that the second identity comes from the fact that we require the elements $x$ to be in $A$ but *not not* in $B$, so they have to lie in $B$.